# Gradle вызвать task из другого task с параметрами cmd

Tags: gradle

В Gradle есть task, который вызывается через cmd с параметрами,
например gradle taskWithParameters -Pparametr1 = 1234

Как вызывать этот task из другого task с параметрами? (параметры предопределены, можно задать в коде)

Comment: Параметры же к прожекту приписываются, т.е. являются свойствами прожекта.  В одном таске записать параметр в свойство прожекта, в другом соответственно извлечь?

Answer (score 2):

Параметры, передающиеся через -P являются properties проекта. Соответственно, их можно дергать из любого task-а просто по их именам (в вашем случае `parametr1`).

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties